# Is there a word for an acronym that spells an existing word?

Tags: vocabulary, acronyms

On a recent episode of The Simpsons, Marge and Homer attended DANK (Drug and Alcohol Night of Knowledge). It made me wonder: is there a term for an acronym that spells an existing word (like how Drug and Alcohol Night of Knowledge's acronym spells the existing word "dank")?

Note that I'm NOT asking about acronyms that form new words, like scuba; although scuba is indeed an acronym, it did not use an already existing word (it created a new word). I'm only asking about acronyms that spell existing words (like how Recording Artists Development uses the existing word RAD as its acronym).

Comment: In general, this is called a back-formation. Reminds me of Dragnet (1987). "[reading from huge lit up sign]

Joe Friday: People... Against... Goodness... And... Normalcy. P, A, G, A, N. P.A.G.A.N.!"  reference: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092925/quotes/?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu

Answer (score 1):

When an acronym spells out a word, it's usually said to be a **contrived acronym**.  From [Wikipedia on acronyms.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym)

> Acronyms are sometimes contrived, that is, deliberately designed to be especially apt for the thing being named (by having a dual meaning or by borrowing the positive connotations of an existing word).

In the example in your question, DANK is definitely a contrived acronym.

Comment: And some acronyms are quite contrived indeed (looking at you, [NASA](https://gizmodo.com/the-only-thing-nasa-is-better-at-than-space-exploration-1744780746)): __T__ wo __W__ ide-Angle __I__ maging __N__ eutral-Atom __S__ pectrometers

Comment: Is there a term for when the acronym doesn't spell an existing word on purpose, or if the existing word's meaning is unrelated to the acronym?

Comment: @nnnnnn Pseudoacroynms and maybe fortuitous acronym?